# Async function not waiting long enough to push firestore docs into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to get a bunch (10-1500) of documents from firestore and then once I have them I check the amount I got, and then handle it from there.

I can only get this to work when I have a manual 'setTimeout' in between grabbing the docs and checking the array.

The array is not being filled with all of the firestore documents before I check for them but it is in an async function so I am confused to why it isn't waiting.

- this is not a firestore issue, I receive all of the documents as I expect.

[image: firestore]

**javascript async function**

```
async function query(units, days){

  try {

    let allLogs = []

    var ts = moment().subtract(days,'days').valueOf() //ms timestamp from 1 -3 days ago


       await units.forEach(async(e) => {

         let ref = db.collection('units').doc(`${e.unit.superId}`).collection('logs').where('info.ms', '>=', parseInt(ts))

         let docs = await ref.get()  // get all subcollection documents from parent document

          await docs.forEach(async(doc) =>{ // Loop through and push all documents to allLogs array

             allLogs.push(doc.data())

           })
       })


     //If i dont add this: it will always think allLogs is empty. Not waiting long enough for it to be filled

     await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, (days+ 1.5) * 1000 )); // x seconds wait for array to be filled


     if (allLogs.length > 0){
       console.log('filled')
     } else {
      console.log('empty')

     }


  } catch(err) {

    console.log(err)
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## forEach does not await callbacks

It fires all calls sequentially and does not await them (it also return undefined, so awaiting it does nothing)

Use a for ... of loop to await each call

```
for (const unit of units) {
    let ref = db.collection('units').doc(`${unit.unit.superId}`).collection('logs').where('info.ms', '>=', parseInt(ts))
    let docs = await ref.get() // get all subcollection documents from parent document
    docs.forEach((doc) => { // Loop through and push all documents to allLogs array
        allLogs.push(doc.data())
    }
}
```

Or fire all promises and await all of them with Promise.all

```
await Promise.all(units.map(async (unit) => {
    let ref = db.collection('units').doc(`${unit.unit.superId}`).collection('logs').where('info.ms', '>=', parseInt(ts))
    let docs = await ref.get()  // get all subcollection documents from parent document
    docs.forEach((doc) => { // Loop through and push all documents to allLogs array
        allLogs.push(doc.data())
    })
}))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: you just save my day : ) i was trying forEach() function but i now i realize to use for of function. agian very useful answer